# Extract values from Django <QuerySet> object

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

I have this Python code for filtering:

```
x_list  = []
x = SupplierCommunication.objects.filter(supplier=supplier.id).values_list("x",flat=True)
x_list.append(x)
```

this code outputs this:

```
x_list:  [<QuerySet ['no']>, <QuerySet ['yes']>]
```

however I want it to be like this

```
x_list = ['no','yes']
```

How can I achive this? I have tried using .values() , .value_list() however none of it worked for me.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your items are still querysets, you iterate over these to get the values, so use `.extend(..)`:

```
x_list = []
x = SupplierCommunication.objects.filter(supplier=supplier.id).values_list(
    'x', flat=True
)
x_list.extend(x)
```